# Conditional probability ordering

Tags: probability

> Bob and Mary have probabilities $0.3$ and $0.2$ to score a goal. Two goals
>   are scored, one of which was from Mary. What is the probability that
>   Bob scored the other one?

**My solution:**

Probability of Mary scoring one of them is $p=MM+MB+BM=0.2^2 +0.2 \times 0.3\times 2$

Probability of Bob scoring one of them is $q=MB+BM=0.3\times0.2\times2$

Hence, the probability is $\dfrac{q}{p}$.

**Question:** Is this solution correct? I am not entirely sure if I should have included both orders $MB$ and $BM$.

Comment: I don't understand the problem description. The probabilities $0.3$ and $0.2$ are for Bob and Mary, respectively, to score **one** goal? If so, isn't it already known that if two goals were scored, Bob scored one of them? And if not, what is the intended interpretation of "probability to score a goal"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being told that Mary scored one from the two goals does not tell you which, so indeed, you should have included the order; and you did.

Edit: But of course $0.2+0.3\neq 1$ so there is a possibility that **someone else** scored the other goal.

The (conditional) probability that Bob scored one from the two goals given that Mary scored at least one is: $1/3$. $$\dfrac{2\cdot 0.2\cdot 0.3}{0.2^2+2\cdot 0.2\cdot 0.8}$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is the assumption that the soccer game has literally two players only?

Comment: Yes.  What of the missing $0.5$?  See the revised answer.